# 301 redirect from friendly url iis7

Tags: php, redirect, joomla, iis-7, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a site in joomla and IIS 7.
Joomla and reformatted my urls amicably .
I changed the name of a category so that old links page gives a 404 error .
What I need is to make a dynamic rule to change the word designating the former category in the url by the word now means the new category to keep access or link the old url.

Example:

http://www.formacionalcala.es/cursos-a-distancia/**aux-enfermeria**/1005/anatomofisiologia-patologias-basicas-detalles

- >

http://www.formacionalcala.es/cursos-a-distancia/**auxiliar-enfermeria**/1005/anatomofisiologia-patologias-basicas-detalles.

Just that one word .
I have tried several rules in the web.config but I have not succeeded.

Thanks and sorry for my bad English .

Answer (score 0):

You Know that Joomla! was born on Lamp and 301 redirect are managed in .htaccess
file (in the root).
Here you can read a Microsoft guide on how to modify .htaccess on IIS7 then you can do, I think, one or more normal 301 redirect.

[Microsoft guide](http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/translate-htaccess-content-to-iis-webconfig)